# SQL SERVER , error in my query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need to know where is the problem in query, and how can I solve this?

***SQL Query :***

```
SELECT 
    P.NameAr, P.NameEn,
    Sum(p.OrderQty) AS SumQty , 
    Sum(p.OrderQty * P.NewPrice) AS SumQtyPrice , 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY D.ProductID ASC) AS Number,
    'Soon' AS ColSoon
FROM OrderMasters M
INNER JOIN OrderDetails D ON D.OrderMasterID = M.OrderMasterID
INNER JOIN Products P ON P.ProductID = D.ProductID
INNER JOIN Categories C ON C.CategoryID = P.CategoryID

GROUP BY P.NameAr, P.NameEn
Order By D.OrderDetailsID
```

***Error Msg :***

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 7

> Column 'OrderDetails.ProductID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

When I remove line consisting `@RowNumber` code execute with no problem, but I need that in query.

Comment: When GROUP BY, only select list columns can be in the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 3):

You can't apply order by field which doesn't belongs to group by;

So, you should change it your order by clauses

```
SELECT 
    P.NameAr, P.NameEn,
    Sum(p.OrderQty) AS SumQty , 
    Sum(p.OrderQty * P.NewPrice) AS SumQtyPrice , 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY P.NameAr ASC) AS Number,
    'Soon' AS ColSoon
FROM OrderMasters M
INNER JOIN OrderDetails D ON D.OrderMasterID = M.OrderMasterID
INNER JOIN Products P ON P.ProductID = D.ProductID
INNER JOIN Categories C ON C.CategoryID = P.CategoryID

GROUP BY P.NameAr, P.NameEn
Order By P.NameAr
```

I put the `P.NameAr` as order field to provide example.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    P.NameAr, P.NameEn,
    Sum(p.OrderQty) AS SumQty , 
    Sum(p.OrderQty * P.NewPrice) AS SumQtyPrice , 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY D.ProductID ASC) AS Number,
    'Soon' AS ColSoon,
    D.OrderDetailsID
FROM OrderMasters M
INNER JOIN OrderDetails D ON D.OrderMasterID = M.OrderMasterID
INNER JOIN Products P ON P.ProductID = D.ProductID
INNER JOIN Categories C ON C.CategoryID = P.CategoryID

GROUP BY P.NameAr, P.NameEn,D.ProductID,D.OrderDetailsID
Order By D.OrderDetailsID
```

**I'm solve this thx all for hints**

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY should contain D.PRODUCTID as well:

```
group by p.NameAr, p.NameEn, d.ProductID
```